# Python list comprehensions: set all elements in an array to 0 or 1

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I've been trying to come up with a one line list comprehension to do the following: Given an array of integers and a single integer, call it int1, I want to create a new array of only 0's and 1's such that the new array has a 1 if there was an int1 at that position in the original array else 0.

Is there a way to have True/False be 1/0 as in C?

```
array1 = [1,4,2,4,5,6,4,3]
array2 = [x == 4 for x in array1 ]
=> [False, True, False, True, False, False, True, False]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply convert the boolean to `int`, with [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function, like this

```
array2 = [int(x == 4) for x in array1]
```

**Output**

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

This works because, in Python, [Boolean is a subclass of `int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool).

Answer (score 2):

Use a conditional expression. `1 if x==4 else 0` or what have you.

Comment: array2 = [1 if x == 4 else 0 for x in array1]

Comment: Please correct your answer as suggested by @MrWardo

Answer (score 2):

`True` and `False` already cast to `int` the way you want them to. Just convert them to `int` directly:

```
>>> [int(t) for t in (True, True, False)]
[1, 1, 0]
```